# How to read file from python csv in html?

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I have a problem that I want to read files from CSV and make a loop in it instead of writing one by one in an html page. How to read and fetch files from csv in HTML using python code in Django. This code is of *index.html*.

```
<body>
<center><h1>Article Writing Sites</h1></center>
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
      {% with open('file.csv') as open%}
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <p>this is next paragraph</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could anyone answer?

Comment: You need to read the csv file in view and pass the contents of the csv as context to the template

Comment: Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Use Django filter tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a view which renders the html given in question. Then you can update the view to open the csv file and read the file. Then send the contents of the csv to html:

```
import csv
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
    csv_output = []
    for dict_item in reader:
        csv_output.append(dict_item)
    return render(request, 'template.html', context={'csv_content':csv_output})
```

Then in template, you need receive that context and iterate through it to show the values in template:

```
{% for content in csv_content %}
    <div class="row">
       {% for k, v in content.items %}
       <div class="column">
           value for {{k }} is {{ v }}
       </div>
       {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want to fetch just first column.